# Requirements to make PWA in a WebAPK format

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am working on my website. I managed to get basic PWA functionality using the web page manifest file.

Not long ago, Google released deeply integrated PWAs, allowing users to make a WebAPK when they added the page into the home screen.

I want my page to also have that kind of feature, but it is never been clear what I should do to get that functionality..

Do I need to add something extra aside from the manifest file, sw.js and various meta tags?

Comment: Did you figure out how to trigger updates of WebAPK if you modify the manifest? I've been struggling with it a bit for some time. Nothing seens to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345192/improved-add-to-homescreen-webapk-icon-name-for-installed-web-app-on-google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not something we can control. Chrome was/is experimenting with ["improved A2HS"](https://joreteg.com/blog/installing-web-apps-for-real) as they called it (A2HS stands for "add to homescreen") and a part of that was an internal service that wrapped the PWA into APK. It was hidden behind a flag initially, then it was [opened to the public as default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen) in Feb 2017.

> When you install a Progressive Web App, **we** look at your Web App Manifest and other meta-data and create the APK that is installed on to the user's device.

(emphasis mine, we == Android)

So there's nothing we can do except being sure our manifest is valid, site is HTTPS, Service Worker installs correctly etc.

Comment: That's kinda a bummer. But after tweaking some sw.js stuff, it actually installed itself as a WebAPK. So thanks for trying to explain.